# Dojo tree collapse/expand error in IE(9)

Tags: internet-explorer, tree, dojo

I have a dojo tree with checkboxes and it works great in FF and Chrome, but not in IE(9). In most of IE cases i could figure out some workaround for that, but this one is just to weird. It happens whenever i try to collapse or expand tree node regardless if it is by user input - pressing on +/- expand button or programmatically- calling TREE._collapseNode(NODE);

This is how tree is created:

```
                this._tocTreeControl = new dijit.Tree({
                    model: this._treeModel,
                    showRoot: false,
                    autoExpand: true,
                    branchIcons: false,
                    nodeIcons: false,
                    "class": "IdentifyFilterTreeRoot",
                    _createTreeNode: function (args) {
                        var tnode = new dijit._TreeNode(args);
                        dojo.attr(tnode.labelNode, "innerHTML", args.label);
                        return tnode;
                    }
                });
```

It throws error in dojo file "dojo/dijit/tree.js"

```
this.expandoNodeText.innerHTML=_2e[idx];
```

or in uncompressed version i believe that is

```
this.expandoNodeText.innerHTML = _a11yStates[idx];
```

this.expandoNodeText.innerHTML is "-" or "+", _2e is array [*,-,+,*], idx is 1 or 2. Something that looks like normal operation throws error in IE(9) "Invalid target element for this operation.".
I were considering option to catch the method "_onExpandoClick" and manually hide/show nodes, but in IE it doesn't reach that event and throws error before that.

Anyone know why is it happening, and what could be some workaround for this?

Comment: what dojo-version do you use? can you provide a fiddle which reproduces the issue?

Comment: Found out what was causing the problem. Updated question!

Answer (score 0):

> After some aditional search found out that IE does not support setting innerHTML inside tag. All the problem was that this tree was inside dojo.DropDownMenu(which is table), so I just changed it to dojo.ContentPane and it all works now.